# Translating SOAP Web services calls into JMX API

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jmx

I have SOAP web services for Application 1 available to me. And, I'd like to implement a Java application that translate Application 1's Web Services calls to Application 2's JMX API. So App 1 can manage a bunch of operations through App 2.

If I understand the problem correctly, I want to build a SOAP/JMX Proxy (Remote Proxy design pattern) as my translation layer. This means it will receive SOAP requests and translate them to JMX, forwarding the translated request and then do the inverse to return the response.

Do you have suggestions on this approach and if there is another way to proceed? Any pointers/corrections are highly appreciated.

Comment: So write a web service who's operations invoke the JMX API...

Comment: Is that equivalent to using the Remote Proxy design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Epitaph, this looks like a repost of your same question [Ideas on how to approach a project involving Integration of APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010083/ideas-on-how-to-approach-a-project-involving-integration-of-apis). In essence, it is the proxy pattern. Your web services are just calling another object via the JMX API.